# pierre simon laplace and his knowledge of the (Laplacian) matrices

Tags: graph-theory, math-history, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

so as we all know, there is a graph matrix called the Laplacian that is used in some eigenvalue/eigenvector/graph theory/spectral theory problems.

i'm wondering if the name of this matrix is referring to THE Pierre-Simon Laplace? If so, is there evidence he knew of matrices, let alone graph matrices? further, what was his application of these matrices to the real-world? i imagine it was akin to cauchy and his stress tensor?

any help would be great

Comment: You can actually read [Laplaces work on Celestial Bodies](https://archive.org/details/elementaryillus00laplgoog), where he first began using what we now think of as the Laplacian differential operator (he was just coming up with natural laws for the behavior of objects and fluids). Now many things are called the Laplacian, often because they play an analogous role in that field of mathematics, or are generalizations (like the Laplace-Beltrami operator on more general Riemannian manifolds).

Comment: thanks for this.is it fair to interpret the graph laplacian from spectral graph theory as a diagrammatic form the of the laplacian differential operator?